# How to select anchors NOT inside CKEditor 4 container

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, ckeditor4.x

On my dynamic HTML page I typically generate one or more instances of CKEditor 4.  I am running jQuery code that should open all clicked links located OUTSIDE the editors, in a new browser tab/window.

The problem is that the jQuery which I use to open anchor clicks in a new window/tab, also causes any click on a CKEditor icon/button to open a new tab.

I use `textarea` tags for the CKEditor container, and each tag has `class='rte'`, for example:

```
<textarea id='rte_test' name='rte_test' class='rte'>HTML Content</textarea>
```

Outside these textarea tags I also have anchors like these:

```
<a href='http://www.example.com/'>GO TO EXAMPLE, BUT IN A NEW WINDOW</a>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).off('click', 'a').on('click', 'a:not(.textarea.rte a)', function(e) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (href) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('<a>').attr('href', href).attr('target', '_blank')[0].click();
        }
        else e.preventDefault();
});";
```

The problem is that the `a:not(.textarea.rte a)` selector is seemingly just ignored.

Comment: The method you're using is correct (ie. `:not()`) however the CKEditor creates it's own HTML structure and the editor appears within that. Therefore you need to inspect the DOM to find a way of targeting that element, not your original `textarea`

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Thank you. When I inspect the dom I see the CKEditor code but I also see my textarea tags still surrounding that. However, it seems to work if I reduce the scope to exclude only the `div` with `class='cke'` which is generated by CKEditor. Problem solved.